# AWS ECS run instance for each microservice

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, amazon-ecs

I suppose, it's a stupid question but I have no idea where to find the answer. I've checked so many resources but I still didn't get it.

I have docker-compose.yml file. Is it possible to use AWS ECS cluster to run a new instance (t2.micro, for example) for each service (eurekaserver, configserver, zuulserver, database)? I saw only examples with one big instance.

```
version: '2'
services:

  eurekaserver:
   image: maxb/tracker-eurekasvr:tracker-eurekasvr
   ports:
       - "8761:8761"

  configserver:
    image: maxb/tracker-confsvr:tracker-confsvr
    ports:
       - "8888:8888"
    environment:
       EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
       EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
       ENCRYPT_KEY:       "IMSYMMETRIC"

  zuulserver:
    image: maxb/tracker-zuulsvr:tracker-zuulsvr
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    environment:
      PROFILE: "default"
      SERVER_PORT: "5555"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:8888"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
      DATABASESERVER_PORT: "27017"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT:   "8761"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT:   "8888"

  database:
    image: mongo
    container_name: tracker-mongo
    volumes:
      - $HOME/tracker-data:/data/db
      - $HOME/tracker-datacd:/data/bkp
    restart: always
```

AWS ECS has Tasks Definitions but I'm not sure if it can help

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to run these services 24x7 and not on demand. With container orchestration it is possible. One way of doing it with Rancher is as below:

Create 5 micro instances. 4 for the services and 1 for Rancher and put all 5 in 1 VPC. Now install Rancher in the 5th instance and add the other 4 hosts in Rancher, so that all your 4 hosts show up in Rancher's infrastructure.

Now label all the 4 hosts in Rancher uniquely - for ex: 'zuulserver' , 'database' , 'configserver' , 'eurekaserver'

Now edit your docker compose to add those rancher host labels to each of your services.

`io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: key1=value1`

```
 wordpress:
  labels:
    # Make wordpress a global service
    io.rancher.scheduler.global: 'true'
    # Make wordpress only run containers on hosts with a key1=value1 label
    io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: key1=value1
    # Make wordpress only run on hosts that do not have a key2=value2 label
    io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label_ne: key2=value2
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - db: mysql
  stdin_open: true
```

In Rancher create a stack with your docker compose and start the stack.

Rancher will deploy those services to the corresponding hosts according to the host affinity labels.

https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.1/en/cattle/scheduling

https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.2/en/hosts/